# Upwork Send Client Offer API call format

Tags: node.js, upwork-api

I'm building out a webservice that uses the Upwork APIs. I’ve been playing with the the Send Client Offer call and have the following code:

```
const Offers = require('upwork-api/lib/routers/hr/clients/offers.js').Offers;
var offers = new Offers(api);

var params = {
    'title': 'this is a test',
    'jobType': 'hourly',
    'chargeRate': '20.0',
    'messageToContractor': 'Please accept this test job',
    'teamReference': '5051328',
    'contractorReference': '~0120735c46bc72dc4f'
    'related_jobcategory2': '1031626745110315008'
};

offers.makeOffer(params, function(error, data) {
    if (error){
        response(context, error.statusCode, 'api.sendClientOffer failed with: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    else {
        ok(context, data);
    }
});
```

This produces following error:

api.sendClientOffer failed with:

```
{"statusCode":400,"data":"{\"server_time\":1574402550,\"error\":{\"status\":\"400\",\"code\":\"1\",\"message\":\"FP2 offers should have at least one milestone defined.\"}}"}
```

Which is confusing because milestones should only be required for fixed-price type, not hourly.

When I add the milestones parameter:

'milestones' : [
        {'milestone_description': 'First milestone', 'deposit_amount': 10.0, 'due_date':'12-15-2019'},
        {'milestone_description': 'Second milestone', 'deposit_amount': 10.0, 'due_date': '12-23-2019'}
    ]

I get api.sendClientOffer failed with:

```
{"statusCode":401,"data":"{\"server_time\":1574402693,\"error\":{\"status\":401,\"code\":401,\"message\":\"Verification of signature failed.\"}}"}
```

The getCompanies call shows that I have access to the team I referenced and my credentials work for the getUserInfo and searchFreelancers calls. Does anyone have a node.js example of this call I can use as a reference? I'm having a hard time figuring out if this is an auth error or validation error.

Comment: Just make sure you are using correct contractorReference and teamReference value

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong parameters, please check the documentation for this API at https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=node#contracts-and-offers_send-client-offer. There is no `jobType` parameter, it's called `job_type`. Same for others.